# Install Apache on RedHat without internet connection

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, linux

How do I install Apache + MySQL + PHP on RedHat server without Internet Connection. I know that i can use YUM to install it but because my servers are inside firewall I can't go outside. Is it possible to use my computer (when I'm connection to RedHat via VPN) as a Proxy? if yes then how is it done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't allow the server access to the Internet while you are installing Apache and turn it back off afterward?

Comment: Not right now, I'm going to need to wait for IT to enable it which will take for ever... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically 2 options

- Download the needed RPMs, copy them to the server and install them manually using rpm -Uvh xxxx.rpm.
- Set up a local yum repository from a mounted DVD with all RPMs for that distro

The first one is the easiest, and was the way you installed packages before all this yum/repos magic got working (RH 7.3 anyone? :-)). This method will fail if some other RPM is needed (dependency), in case you will also have to download that RPM and include it in the command line.

The second one is better. Involves mounting the DVD, use "createrepo" to create repository fils and setup a repo on /etc/yum.repos.d using "baseurl=file://path/to/repo.data.."

[Here](http://kezhong.wordpress.com/2009/06/19/setting-up-a-local-yum-server/) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd mount DVD that you used to install REDHAT and create yum.repo file and install it off of that disk, all files that you need is already on that disk, worse case scenario just use rpm -ivh file from that directory and you should be able install it even without yum

Comment: or download the .rpm files to a usb stick, then use good ol' sneaker-net

Answer (score 0):

At least you mount your RHEL DVD to your server or not. Other wise your can copy all the rpm from your DVD to your server and createrepo file for the same why your have create repository bcoz of dependency then you can use yum install apache mysql php or use rpm -ivh name of the packest.