# Yum Install Packages Behind Firewall

Tags: firewall, proxy, centos7, yum

I have a CentOS 7 server (server X)in a datacenter that has a firewall that I couldn't do yum:

```
# yum search htop
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=extras&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=updates&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * extras: mirrors.shu.edu.cn
 * updates: ftp.sjtu.edu.cn
Warning: No matches found for: htop
No matches found
```

And the datacenter doesn't offer a proxy server for me to yum install anything.

However, I can ssh to server X from my home computer over Internet + VPN.

I just wonder whether there is a way to utilize the ssh connection to yum install packages (or any other ways to yum install packages).

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/66077/install-apache-on-redhat-without-internet-connection) suggested that people just install with RPMs or DVD.

I think installing from RPMs are simple if there isn't any dependency but it will be troublesome to deal with dependency.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Update 1:
I couldn't even ping the IP of mirrorlist.centos.org (although it is pingable):

```
# ping 85.236.43.108
PING 85.236.43.108 (85.236.43.108) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 85.236.43.108 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

So the DNS resolution isn't the root cause.

Traceroute indicates the traffic is blocked:

```
# traceroute 85.236.43.108
traceroute to 85.236.43.108 (85.236.43.108), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (172.18.22.254)  3.884 ms  4.100 ms  4.322 ms
 2  gateway (172.18.22.254)  3.200 ms !H * *
```

It couldn't go out because the datacenter has a firewall.  Server X itself has no firewall nor iptable to prevent going out.

Update 2: downloading rpms and rsync-ing and then installing failed

```
# yum localinstall /tmp/audit-libs-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm --disablerepo=*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining /tmp/audit-libs-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: audit-libs-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64
Marking /tmp/audit-libs-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm as an update to audit-libs-2.7.6-3.el7.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package audit-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.6-3.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: audit-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.6-3.el7 for package: audit-2.7.6-3.el7.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
---> Package audit-libs.x86_64 0:2.8.1-3.el7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: audit-2.7.6-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: audit-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.6-3.el7
           Removing: audit-libs-2.7.6-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               audit-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.6-3.el7
           Updated By: audit-libs-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64 (/audit-libs-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64)
               audit-libs(x86-64) = 2.8.1-3.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Please note that the error *”could not resolve host”* is a DNS resolution error that usually is the result of incorrect or missing name servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` , what happens when you fix that?

Comment: @HBruijn good eye!  But actually it doesn't really matter because the data center doesn't really offer a DNS server.  For instance, I couldn't ping the IP of mirrorlist.centos.org: # ping 85.236.43.108
PING 85.236.43.108 (85.236.43.108) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 85.236.43.108 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms

Comment: Is this server meant to be able to access the Internet? You should have a chat with the datacenter about that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did.  It doesn't mean to have access.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you need a new datacenter.

Comment: Haha, unfortunately, it is not an option.

Comment: So, how do they expect you to install OS updates, or even the packages you want to install today?! This is really bizarre.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  Checking with the datacenter to see how much they charge for allowing internet access.

Comment: Checked.  Close to 1K USD/mo...geez.  I guess I will try to go through the pain of setting up my local repos.  Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to create similar environment on vm using virtualbox or similar tool, then download the packages on the vm using yum-downloadonly. Create an iso of these package OR create your own repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have related and established connections allowed in via the firewall or else the response won’t be able to come back in

Comment: The firewall disallows server X to access anywhere but allows external to initiate a SSH connection over VPN.  I am trying to figure given such criteria whether there is a way to install packages indirectly from a repos over yum.  Thanks.

Comment: Nope that won’t work or else you won’t be able to request anything. You’ll have to obtain the rpm and rsync them to it

Comment: So what's the industry standard way to install in this kind of data center? Downloading rpms with dependencies and then rsync-ing?

Comment: No. Here’s the thing... your overall setup is not industry standard... I don’t really get what you’re trying to achieve having firewalled outgoing and incoming... what about OS patches.. etc. Etc. It doesn’t cater to the most important thing. Meltdown and spectre patches to start with..

Comment: I could advise further if you could tell me the firewall? Eg. External firewall device or iptables on local server

Comment: External.  No iptables/firewall daemon on my server.

Comment: Allow all outgoing connection.. allow incoming related/established connections then if you really want then firewall outgoing with iptables with the exception of an allow rule above it for if the connection is from a program/cmd run as root

Comment: The external firewall device is owned by the datacenter.  So I have no control.

Comment: Surely you can submit firewall change requests...

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is an exchange in a 3rd world country.  All machines there are under the same rule.

Comment: I think your only option is to rsync the rpms to the machine